# Is a method that returns a Try allowed to throw?

Tags: java, exception, api-design, vavr

We're using [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) in our project to ease exception handling. I always make sure that a method that returns a [`Try`](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_try) can never throw anything, like so:

```java
public Try<Result> someSafeMethod() {
  return Try.of(() -> someService.generateId())
           .map(someOtherService::getValueForId)
           .map(mappingService::mapToResult);
}
```

but some of my colleagues would implement it like this:

```java
public Try<Result> someSafeMethod() {
  String generatedId = someService.generateId(); // <- Might throw an Exception that is not caught by the Try clause
  return Try.of(() -> someOtherService.getValueForId(generatedId))
           .map(mappingService::mapToResult);
}
```

Arguing that if something is wrong with the generation of the ID that they would rather the exception is thrown instead of the returned `Try` being a failure.

The documentation does not prohibit that a method returning a `Try` should not throw, but it does state that:

> Try is a monadic container type which represents a computation that **may either result in an exception, or return a successfully computed value**.

Am I being too too strict? Imagine you would use an API where all methods return a `Try`, wouldn't it be bad when they still throw?

Comment: Personally I would prefer your view that all "failure" is returned via the return value. From the perspective of a user of an interface declaring a Try as return value, I would expect that I can rely on all failure being returned that way (otherwise I would have to implement two different handlings for the failure).

Comment: It _can_ according to the language spec, but it really _shouldn't_ as a matter of good practice: You're adopting a different control model and should use that consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not being too strict.

The whole point of using `Try` as a return value is the resulting benefit of programming with total functions and having a composable way of handling errors. Total functions are functions that always return a value of the declared return type for all possible argument values. If they are throwing exceptions, their functions are not total functions anymore, and—without explicit error handling—non-totality will propagate transitively through their code, 'infecting' all other functions that call them with non-totality. As a result, they will end up with code that will be much harder to reason about and it will take more effort to make sure it is correct.

Throwing exceptions while using `Try` would also defy the purpose of using `Try` in the first place and it would unnecessarily complicate the code consuming their API for no obvious benefit, because the API consumers will have to do error handling both using `Try` and catching exceptions.